# Can Julia handle typed arrays with elements of more than 1 type?

Tags: arrays, types, julia, hierarchy

I want to have a constructor/method accept an array, but that array can only contain elements of 2 different types.
For example:

```
Array{Union{Int64, String}} = [1, 2, "3"]
```

But now I want to create the array as `[1, 2, "3"]` (not specifying the type) and have it automatically be accepted by the constructor who's expecting arguments of type `::Array{Union{Int64, String}}`.
What happens is that `[1, 2, "3"]` is by default of type `Any`, and therefore not accepted by my constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array like that as follows:

```
julia> Union{Int64, String}[1, 2, "3"]
3-element Array{Union{Int64, String},1}:
 1   
 2   
  "3"
```

The documentation for this in the manual can be [found here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Typed-array-initializers-1). To quote the manual,

> An array with a specific element type can be constructed using the syntax T[A, B, C, ...]. This will construct a 1-d array with element type T, initialized to contain elements A, B, C, etc.

Comment: You can also create an alias for the union `const IntStr = Union{Int, String}` which you can use anywhere a type is expected `IntStr[1, 2, "3"]`, `foo(x::AbstractArray{<:IntStr}) = println("An IntStr array!")`.

Comment: Good point. Though `foo(x::AbstractArray{IntStr})` might make more sense, since `IntStr` is a concrete type.